# Get delimited columns values into different rows using sqoop and hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, sqoop, bigdata

I have the below data in one of my oracle db tables -

```
ZONE_ID,ZONE_NAME,OPERATORS,GEOGRAPHIES,PRODUCT_ID
3285,'EUROPE',null,'3,6,14,21,32',2
3293,'USA AND MEXICO',null,'133,215',3
3061,'Europe','11,238,352,398',null,4
3221,'USA','1079',null,5
```

In operators and geographies columns, data is comma delimited. For each row, data is either there in operators column or geographies column.

I need to get this delimited data in separate rows as below :

```
ZONE_ID,ZONE_NAME,OPERATORS,GEOGRAPHIES,PRODUCT_ID
3285,'EUROPE',null,3,2
3285,'EUROPE',null,6,2
3285,'EUROPE',null,14,2
3285,'EUROPE',null,21,2
3285,'EUROPE',null,32,2
3293,'USA AND MEXICO',null,133,3
3293,'USA AND MEXICO',null,215,3
3061,'Europe',11,null,4
3061,'Europe',238,null,4
3061,'Europe',352,null,4
3061,'Europe',398,null,4
3221,'USA',1079,null,5
```

Is this transformation possible during sqoop import from oracle db?  Else how can we import this data using sqoop and do this transformation in hive.

Please help.

Comment: **1.** Import the data to HDFS text files but make sure Sqoop uses another field separator (just be careful to use a plain ASCII char e.g. `;` or `|`) **2.** create a Hive "EXTERNAL" table on the text files, defining explicitly the field separator (what you set for Sqoop) and the array separator (comma), and defining the GEOGRAPHIES col as type ARRAY **3.** `explode` the array within a SELECT cf. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode

Comment: @Samson Scharfrichter I was thinking about the same. But need to expode both Operators and Geographies columns as both of them have delimited data, basis For each row, data is either there in operators column or geographies column.  How will explode work on both columns simultaneously? Thanks much.

Comment: `explode` on multiple columns will result in partial-cartesian-products; in your case it does not really matter because you never have data in both cols. In other cases, when you have to match X[1] and Y[1], X[2] and Y[2] etc. you would have to `posexplode` then weed out the mismatched records (e.g. X[1] and Y[2]) in a further WHERE clause -- not very efficient but it works.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter I actually got a requirement where data is present in both columns. I'm not able to resolve it using posexplode. Please help. If i have data this way- 3285,'EUROPE','133,215','3,6',2 .   I need it this way-                                            3285,'EUROPE','133',null,2
3285,'EUROPE','215',null,2
3285,'EUROPE',null,'3',2
3285,'EUROPE',null,'6',2

Comment: Then run two different queries, one with `EXPLODE(operators) WHERE operators IS NOT NULL` and the other with `EXPLODE(geographies) WHERE geographies IS NOT NULL`, then `UNION ALL` to merge the results at run-time.

Comment: @SamsonScharfrichter Thanks much. I've another requirement coming up. Posted it as a different question- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37646311/mapping-of-fields-in-two-array-columns-in-hive. Would you please mind helping me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working using below query in hive:

```
select ZONE_ID
,ZONE_NAME
,col1
,col2
,product_id
from table
lateral view explode(OPERATORS) ptable1 as col1
lateral view explode(GEOGRAPHIES) ptable2 as col2
;
```